# Suppress server message in rsync

Tags: rsync, scp, error-handling

When I `rsync` or `scp` from a particular server I get a rather long message telling me the rules of the server. However when I setup regular pulls, I'd like to be able to suppress those messages in my logs. Looking through the man page suggest that `-q` should work, but that only quiets messages from scp itself.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For rsync, it has a `--no-motd` you can use to suppress the motd for your script and only see the output of what rsync is transferring. It looks like it was added in rsync 3.x since I don't see that option in 2.x.

The man page lists a caveat about not using it when trying to get a listing of modules you can rsync:

> --no-motd
>
> This  option affects the information that is output by the client at
>   the start of a daemon transfer.  This suppresses the
>   message-of-the-day (MOTD) text, but it also affects the list of
>   modules that the daemon sends in response to the "rsync host::"
>   request (due to a limitation in the rsync protocol), so omit this
>   option if you want to request the list of modules from the daemon.

For scp, trying touching the file `~/.hushlogin`. When I scp files, I don't see the motd though but your set up might be different. The man page for `login` has more info:

> If the  file .hushlogin exists, then a "quiet" login is performed
>   (this disables the checking of mail and the printing of the last login
>   time and message of the day).  Otherwise, if /var/log/lastlog exists,
>   the last login time is printed (and the current login is recorded).

Comment: `rsync --no-motd` does not work for me. The SSH MOTD is still being shown.

Answer (score 24):

In case you don't want to mess with your local `~/.ssh/config` file and the `--no-motd` option is not working for you either, I had success setting the `RSYNC_RSH` env variable.

```
RSYNC_RSH="ssh -q" rsync
```

You may also try to use the rsync option `-e`

```
rsync -e 'ssh -q'
```

Comment: That worked for me when `--no-motd` failed.

Answer (score 6):

If your version of `rsync` doesn't support the `--no-motd` option, 
puting `LogLevel quiet` in `~/.ssh/config` will do the trick.

Comment: The `LogLevel quiet` option worked for me. _Note_: I did have to _create_ the file (`~/.ssh/config`), but I put in the one line, and voila! no more `/etc/issue.net` showing up!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably suppress the motd by redirecting `STDERR` to /dev/null, but that way you will miss all other error messages too.

```
scp src dst 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: This is not an option, all output is being directed to a log file that needs review later - errors are important!

Comment: Well stop being too biased. I think his solution is better than someone who suggested `LogLevel quiet` option which by the way suppressed all warnings and errors.

Answer (score 1):

On my SuSE 11 system, I found the banner message in /etc/issue.net and then remarked out the banner line in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

```
#banner /etc/issue.net
```

Then restarted the ssh daemon

```
service sshd restart
```

This suppressed the banner when using scp inside scripts and cleaned up the log files.

Comment: If the contents of `issue.net` must be shown, put them in a static `/etc/motd` or add it to whatever generates that file, and enable `PrintMotd` in `sshd`'s config (default is enabled). That way it will be visible for interactive logins.